# SQL Select table1.columa as table1.columb

Tags: sql, mysql, select, join

I am working on a database join and I want to do the following:

```
Select tabel_one.id, 
       tabel_one.title, 
       tabel_one.content, 
       table_two.value as table_two.key 
  from tabel_one 
  Join table_two ON table_two.id = table_one.id ....
```

The Important part is:

```
table_two.value as table_two.key
```

Is there a way this could work?

Comment: Yes, but not the way you wrote it.  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Posting some data and expected output would really help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot define an alias referencing a table.

In general, you should simply use:

```
table_two.value as key
```

Otherwise, as [OMG Ponies suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602967/sql-select-table1-columa-as-table1-columb/2603016#2603016), you can wrap the alias in backticks:

```
table_two.value as `table_two.key`
```

Comment: Well, that does not work. To specifiy: I have a table with posts and a table with data for this posts. The data table ist the one joined.
The structure of this one is:
´id ; post_id ; type ; value´

but type could be 'tags' or 'author' you never know.
So I want to join 'post_data.value as post_data.type'.
post_data.type must of course be not written, but be 'tags' or 'author'. Did I understand you correct, that this is impossible?

Comment: Nope, I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @Lukas The column names are fixed for all rows in the result set.  You can have one set with tags and a separate set with author or even one with tags and author (with only one non-NULL) using appropriate logic.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
Select tabel_one.id, 
       tabel_one.title, 
       tabel_one.content, 
       table_two.value as `table_two.key` 
  from tabel_one 
  Join table_two ON table_two.id = table_one.id
```

...works for me on MySQL 5.1.35.  Because of the period, you need to enclose the alias with backticks

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your [comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602967/sql-select-table1-columa-as-table1-columb/2602994#2602994), I expect what you really want is:

```
Select tabel_one.id,  
       tabel_one.title,  
       tabel_one.content,  
       table_two.value as tags,
       table_three.value as author
  from table_one  
  LEFT Join table_two ON table_two.id = table_one.id 
  AND table_two.key= 'tags'
  LEFT Join table_three ON table_three.id = table_one.id 
  AND table_three.key= 'author'
```

Comment: Well, not quite, because firstly, author and tags are bot in the same table and secondly, you never know which one is in the table. I am going to use a different method though. Thanks anyway.